# Bash evaluation: [ vs ||

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a pid stored in a file:

```
echo 394 > pid_stored
```

I'm checking if a pid is running with:

```
kill -0 $(cat pid_stored) 2> /dev/null || echo "PID not running"
```

which works like a charm, but if I want to do multiple actions in the true or false case I guess I need a if then fi structure. But for some reason I can't figure out [ or [[ do not evaluate in the same way:

```
if [[ $(kill -0 $(cat pid_stored) 2> /dev/null) ]]
then echo "PID IS NOT RUNNING"
fi
```

does not work, it always evaluates as true. The error streams get directed with 2> to /dev/null since kill -0 evaluates as true if the pid exists or fails

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `[[ and ]]` since that is used for evaluating an expression:

```
if kill -0 $(<pid_stored) 2> /dev/null
then
   echo "PID IS RUNNING"
else
   echo "PID IS NOT RUNNING"
fi
```

**PS:** You can avoid `cat` also with `$(<pid_stored)`

To negate you can use:

```
if ! kill -0 $(<pid_stored) 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, curiosity: I have to negate the expression with ! I guess that correlates to the || operator? If you want to correct it in your example code in case someone finds this answer it would be the other way round: if ! kill -0 $(<pid_stored) 2> /dev/null

Comment: sure I added to my answer.

Comment: I actually run the script as a background process with `nohup`, then the `$(<pid_stored)` expression seems not to work but `cat` does ... any ideas on why/how? does `nohup` break the redirect operator?  Seems saver to stick with cat since a script like this in unlikely to run in the foreground ..

Comment: Hmm can you do `cat -vte pid_stored` to check what is stored there?

Comment: `cat -vte pid_stored 
26185$`

Comment: Do you still have issues? Can you edit your question and show the output as code in comments isn't easy to read.